# Ubuntu 14.04 is making screenshots automatically without my interaction

Tags: 14.04, screenshot, print-screen

From yesterday, working on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS notebook I noticed that the system is making screenshots automatically without my interaction at different time intervals. "Save screenshot" window appear every time.

Is it a virus or someone spying me?

I tried to find an answer already but it seems that no one ever had a problem like me.

Comment: Are you sure your PrintScreen key isn't stuck?

Answer (score 0):

It is annoying, I agree. But the solution is simple enough.

Go to System settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts. You will find a whole group of shortcuts associated with Screenshots. Simply disable all active shortcuts.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ok, but what keyboard shortcuts have to do with my issue? Even if I leave my computer alone for eg. 1h it does the screenshots as well. without pressing any key